# Discord.js role.setColor() перестал рабоать

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Дело в этом, что изначально код работает исправно, каждую секунду меняет цвет, но примерно через 30 минут бот перестает менять цвет роли, что с этим делать?

```
var roles =client.guilds.cache.get("id сервера").roles.cache.get("id роли")
genGradient(roles.color)
console.log(gradient)
var counter =0
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(counter+"    "+roles.color)
        roles.setColor(gradient[counter])
        counter++
if(counter==100)
{
counter=0
genGradient(roles.color)
}
    },1000)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord запретил использовать данную функцию. Поэтому стоит лимит. Не советую пользоваться данной функцией

Comment: Я уже нашёл ответ, но все равно спасибо)